# android: inflate Toast not get clickEvents on 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-layout

The following code work well on ICS and not on 2.3.3.

I use a custom Toast with a CheckBox and the clickEvents is fired on ICS.

Do I have to create a custom dialog and call it as activity or I can solve it?

```
public void showToastwithImage(String text, int imageID, boolean forceShow) {

    if (prefs.getBoolean("prefs_showHelp", true)) {
        // create the view
        View view = inflateView(R.layout.message_panel);

        // set the image in the view
        ImageView im = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.panel_icon);
        im.setImageResource(imageID);

        // set the text in the view
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        tv.setText(text);

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        if(forceShow){
            cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("prefs_showHelp", false);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
        }


        // show the toast
        Toast toast = new Toast(this);
        toast.setView(view);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

}
private View inflateView(int resource) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    return vi.inflate(resource, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`custom dialog is better than toast...`

You can set view easily in custom dialog....and toast is for flash message without interact it.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);

ImageView im = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.panel_icon);
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Toasts are supposed to use for displaying short messages without offering any user interactions because they are visible for either 2 or 3.5 seconds of duration. Hence, I would suggest you to use Dialog or Activity (with dialog theme) for user to interact with your CheckBox.